# ffmpeg does not decode some h264 streams

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, decoder

I have some ip of cameras on the local network.I receive video stream with live555 library (I took testRtspClient as a basis) and decode frames with ffmpeg  (avcodec_decode_video2). Everything perfectly works.
Problems begin when I try to decode a stream from an internet.

The first problem - some packets lost, so defects appears. But it's not a problem. Problem - after stop and start video stream it is necessary to wait for about 5 minutes of streaming before ffmpeg is able to decode something from the same ip camera. If packets doesn't lost then everithing ok.

The second problem - there is camera which sends video with resolution 2048х1538. The frame of such resolution is sent by several packets. live555 normally brings together them but when the frame is transferred to the decoder, the decoder returns the packet length, but got frame always 0.

Here some my code:

```
#define RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE 1000000
AVCodecContext* avCodecContext; //definition
AVFrame *frame;  //definition
...
//init code
_fReceiveBuffer = new uint8_t[RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE+512]; //buffer to receive frame
ZeroMemory(_fReceiveBuffer, RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE + 512); //zeros
_bufferSize = RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(uint8_t); //buffer size

static const  uint8_t startCode[4] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 }; //this is for 0 0 0 1
//before frame will transfer to decoder
memcpy(_fReceiveBuffer, (void*)startCode, sizeof(uint8_t)* 4);
_fReceiveBuffer += sizeof(sizeof(uint8_t)* 4);
_bufferSize -= sizeof(sizeof(uint8_t)* 4);

AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264); //find codec

avCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec); 
avCodecContext->flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
avcodec_open2(avCodecContext, codec, NULL);

frame = av_frame_alloc();

//frame
void DummySink::afterGettingFrame(unsigned frameSize, unsigned numTruncatedBytes,
struct timeval presentationTime, unsigned durationInMicroseconds) {

if (strcmp(fSubsession.codecName(), "H264") == 0)
{
    //code from onvif device manager
    static const uint8_t startCode3[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };
    static const uint8_t startCode4[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };
    auto correctedFrameSize = frameSize;
    auto correctedBufferPtr = fPlObj->_fReceiveBuffer;
    if (frameSize < sizeof(startCode4) || memcmp(startCode4, correctedBufferPtr, sizeof(startCode4)) != 0){
        if (frameSize < sizeof(startCode3) || memcmp(startCode3, correctedBufferPtr, sizeof(startCode3)) != 0){
            correctedFrameSize += sizeof(uint8_t)* 4;
            correctedBufferPtr -= sizeof(uint8_t)* 4;
        }
    }

    ProcessFrame(correctedBufferPtr, correctedFrameSize, presentationTime, durationInMicroseconds);
}
continuePlaying();
}

void DummySink::ProcessFrame(unsigned char* framePtr, int frameSize, struct timeval presentationTime, unsigned duration)    {

AVPacket avpkt;
av_init_packet(&avpkt);
avpkt.data = framePtr;
avpkt.size = frameSize;
while (avpkt.size > 0) {
    int got_frame = 0;

    int len = avcodec_decode_video2(avCodecContext, frame, &got_frame, &avpkt);
    if (len < 0) {
        //TODO: log error
        return;
    }
    else if (got_frame == 0)
    {
//I tried this code, bacause "codecs which have the AV_CODEC_CAP_DELAY capability set have a delay between input and output"
//but it didn't help
        /*AVPacket emptyPacket;
        av_init_packet(&emptyPacket);
        emptyPacket.data = NULL;
        emptyPacket.size = 0;
        emptyPacket.stream_index = avpkt.stream_index;
        len = avcodec_decode_video2(avCodecContext, frame, &got_frame, &emptyPacket);
        if ( got_frame == 1) goto next;*/
        return;
    }
next:
    //... here code for view with DirectDraw - everithing ok with it
    avpkt.size -= len;
    avpkt.data += len;
}
}
```

I alsa tried to send frame to decoder with sps and pps information:

```
0 0 0 1 sps 0 0 0 1 pps 0 0 0 1 frame
```

but it is not help.

Interesting that avcodec_decode_video2 does not return frame with second problem (return all size of frame), but width and height in avCodecContext are set correctly. I can't understart why it doesn't return frame.

Can anyone help with these problems?

Comment: how many frames did you observe returning no frame in second problem? As per H264, it is not necessarily to give out the frame for display, immediately after decode. Decode and display orders are different in H264. So, I suggest you check for more than 16 frames in general to find any frame for display

Comment: Thanks for the information. During the testing the second problem was the result of the first. If I start program first time - ok, second time - much more than 16 frames received and nothing decoding. But then I decide use rtp over tcp instead of rtp over udp - the problems dissapeared. If rtp uses udp then about 1 packets in 50-100 lost, but I can't understand why it so critical when I run program second and more times.

Comment: probably your encoder creates IPPPPPP..... and after approx. 5 min the second I Frame appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved these problems by using rtp over tcp instead rtp over udp.